# How to get data from JavaScript to Angular2+ component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using current Angular 7. I am using recorderjs to record audio. My set up is like this.

In Angular Component:
Step 1: Import Main.JS

```
import {mainmodule} from '../../shared/scripts/recorderjs/main.js';
```

Step 2: Call record function of Main.Js from Angular Function.

```
mainmodule.toggleRecordingMethod(e); //inside angular component
```

this method will either start recording or will stop the recording.

Step 3: Main.js will use recorderjs to record audio.

```
// This will be called from angular component (Inside main.js).
main.prototype.toggleRecordingMethod = function toggleRecordingMethod(e) {
    enableRecordingVisualization = true;       
    toggleRecording(e);        
};

// inside main.js
function toggleRecording(e) {    
    if (e.classList.contains("recording")) {       
        // stop recording
        audioRecorder.stop();
        e.classList.remove("recording");
        e.classList.remove("pause");   
        enableRecordingVisualization = false; 
        audioRecorder.getBuffer(gotBuffers);        
    } else {
        // start recording
        if (!audioRecorder) {
            initAudio();
        } 

        e.classList.add("recording");
        audioRecorder.clear();                    
    }    
}
```

Till step 3, i am successful. Now main.js which uses recorderjs to record audio is working and recording audio.

In main.js i have following function. it returns undefined in Angular. I have set up breakpoints and i found that javascript immediately retuns undefined rather than waiting for exportWAV to return audio.

```
main.prototype.saveRecordingMethod = function saveRecordingMethod() {   
return audioRecorder.exportWAV(function(blob){return blob;});          
};
```

exportWAV is function from recorderjs which accepts call back.I have passed callback which returns blob which is audio. How do i get audio blob rather than undefined?

I want to send this recorded audio in angular. How do i do that?

Comment: try this : 

`main.prototype.saveRecordingMethod = async function saveRecordingMethod() {`

`let result = await audioRecorder.exportWAV(function(blob){return blob;});`

`return result};`

Comment: I have already tried this. still i get 'undefined'.

Comment: well in that case, a stackblitz replica of the issue will be helpful to us.